# Angular JS ng-show throws "TypeError: f is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-resource, ng-show

I'm working on a gallery page template that takes in an object and uses ng-show or ng-hide to display certain information if the object contains it.  Each instance of ng-show or ng-hide I use creates a "TypeError: f is not a function" error.

I'm using a factory to load a json file containing an array of all the painting objects.  I then use $filter to locate the specific object that I will be using for the individual painting page. I then use a $scope variable to expose the object to the template.

An example object that I am using:

```
{
     "category" : "Flowers",
     "filename" : "swami",
     "location" : "",
     "medium" : "canvas",
     "notes" : "",
     "paint" : "oil",
     "price" : 400,
     "size" : "16x20",
     "title" : "Swami (Day Lily)"
  }
```

Here is a section of the template:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="gallery-tile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 painting-col">

                <h1>{{painting.title}}</h1>
                <p><em>{{painting.paint}} on a {{painting.size}} inch {{painting.medium}}</em></p>
                <p ng-show="location"><strong>Location:</strong> {{painting.location}}</p>
                <p ng-show="notes"><strong>Notes:</strong> {{painting.notes}}</p>
                <hr>
                <p ng-show="painting.price"><strong>Price:</strong> {{painting.price | currency}}</p>
                <p ng-hide="painting.price"><em>This painting is not available for sale.</em></p>

                <br> 
                <a href="#/contact" ng-show="painting.price" class="order-link hvr-icon-forward">Order Policy</a>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <a href="images/max/{{painting.filename}}.jpg" data-featherlight="image">
                    <img ng-src="images/full/{{painting.filename}}.jpg" class="painting-detail" />
                </a>
                <p class="text-muted">Click on the painting for a larger view.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page controller:

```
cpControllers.controller('PaintingDetail', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', 
'$filter', 'Painting', 
function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $filter, Painting) {

    Painting.get().$promise.then(function(response) {
        $scope.painting = $filter('filter')(response.paintings, {filename: $routeParams.painting})[0];

        if ($scope.painting.notes != "") {
            $scope.notes = true
        } else {
            $scope.notes = false
        }
        if ($scope.painting.location != "") {
            $scope.location = true
        } else {
            $scope.location = false
        }

    });

}]);
```

The factory:

```
cpServices.factory('Painting', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource('paintings/paintings.json', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET'},
    });
}]);
```

Finally, the error (not enough reputation for an image...) as is seen in the browser console:

```
11 angular.js:11655 TypeError: f is not a function
at angular.js:16299
at e (angular.js:4924)
at angular.js:5312
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Upload.upload is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072486/typeerror-upload-upload-is-not-a-function)