# TypeError: Upload.upload is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have this function, and it throw exception:

```
$scope.uploadAvatar = function(avatar, user) {
   Upload.upload({
        url: 'api/v1/user' + user.id + '/',
        avatar: avatar,
        method: 'put'
    })
};
```

> TypeError: Upload.upload is not a function

My scripts includes:

```
    <script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/posts_controller.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery.equalheights.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/video.js/video.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/ng-file-upload/FileAPI.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload-all.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
```

So I did inject 'Upload' in my controller and 'ngFileUpload' in module
My controller:

```
myApp.controller('ShowsListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', '$route', 'Upload', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $route, Upload) {

    $http.get('/api/v1/shows/').success(function (data) {
        $scope.shows = data;
    });


    $http.get('/check_login/').success(function (data) {
        $scope.mediaurl = data.mediaUrl;
        $scope.user = data;

    });



    $http.get('/api/v1/actors/').success(function (data) {
        $scope.actors = data;
    });

    $http.get('/api/v1/users/').success(function (data) {
        $scope.users = data;
    });


    $scope.uploadAvatar = function (avatar, user) {

        Upload.upload({
            url: 'api/v1/users' + user.id + '/',
            avatar: avatar,
            method: 'put'
        })
    };

}]);
```

Add my controller with these function

Comment: If there is function Upload, have you your code in $(document).on( "ready", function(){});  ?

Comment: I put this upload function in my controler, and i have no $(document).ready(function{}

Comment: And do you initializing your controller after document is ready?

Comment: @JaroslavŠtreit what do u mean by initialzing controller after document ready?/

Comment: Show me your controller

Comment: @JaroslavŠtreit i did it

Comment: @AlexandrDomoryonok why do you include script `ng-file-upload.js` twice?
Besides, if your `uploadAvatar` method exists in main.js, should it be included as the last one?

Comment: @ASergey uploadAvatar in posts_controller.js

Comment: @AlexandrDomoryonok you just forgot to put `$location`  in the controller function and that cause the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller declaration, you injected `$location` after `$routeParams` but you forgot to pass it in the function.

Since you are using **inline array annotation**, you need  to keep the annotation array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration itself.

```
myApp.controller('ShowsListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', '$route', 'Upload', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, $route, Upload) {
 // your current code
}
```

See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) for more info.